# Dealing with dataframes of relationships between variables

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

I have two dataframes which describe the relationship between three types of variables. These dataframes look like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("y1", "y2", "y3"), 
                  x1 = c(1, 0, 0), 
                  x2 = c(0, 1, 0), 
                  x3 = c(0, 1, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(item = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), 
                  x1 = c(1, 1, 1), 
                  x2 = c(0, 1, 0), 
                  x3 = c(0, 1, 1))
```

In essence, x variables labelled in the colnames of each dataframe explain the relationships between the y and z variables. What I'd like as an output is a variable for each of y1, y2, and y3. Each variable should be a vector of the z variables that match up with it. For example, y1 should contain c(z1, z2, z3), because y1 corresponds to x1, and x1 corresponds to all three of the z items.

I have tried all manner of nested for loops and apply statements, and have thus far been unable to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  gather(k, v1, -id) %>% 
  filter(v1 != 0) %>% 
  inner_join(gather(df2, k,v2, -item) %>% filter(v2 != 0), by="k") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(n=paste(unique(item), collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      id        n
  <fctr>    <chr>
1     y1 z1,z2,z3
2     y2    z2,z3
3     y3    z2,z3
```

Or try it `rowwise`

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(k, v1, -id) %>%  
  filter(v1 != 0) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(res=paste(df2$item[ select(df2, k) == 1 ], collapse=",")) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      id     k    v1      res
  <fctr> <chr> <dbl>    <chr>
1     y1    x1     1 z1,z2,z3
2     y2    x2     1       z2
3     y2    x3     1    z2,z3
4     y3    x3     1    z2,z3
```